# Maven fails with tomcat-maven-plugin since this morning

Tags: maven-2, tomcat, plugins

Since this morning Maven can not build any project that requires tomcat-maven-plugin. I tried with the minimalistic pom.xml, with just that one dependency, but in all cases I get the following:

> [INFO] Error building POM (may not be
>   this project's POM).
>
> Project ID:
>   org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin
>
> Reason: Error getting POM for
>   'org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin'
>   from the repository: Unable to read
>   local copy of metadata: Cannot read
>   metadata from
>   'C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\tomcat-maven-plugin\maven-metadata-codehaus releases.xml': end tag name 
>   must match start tag name
>
> ---
>
> from
>   line 7 (position: TEXT seen
>   ...\n... @9:8)
>   org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:pom:LATEST
>
> for project
>   org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin

First, I tried deleting the local data and redownloading, but I just got checksum failures.
I opened maven-metadata-codehaus releases.xml just to see this inside:

> 301
>   Moved Permanently
>
> ## Moved
>   Permanently
>
> The document has
>   moved https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases/org/codehaus/mojo/tomcat-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml here.
>
> ---
>
> Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat)
>   Server at repository.codehaus.org Port
>   80

I tired changing versions and repositories, but nothing helped. Any ideas anyone?

P.S.
Here's the minimal pom I tried with:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
<id>Codehaus Snapshots</id>
<url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
<releases>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</releases>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
<finalName>my-webapp</finalName>
<plugins>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the redirection is incorrect, Codehaus Snapshots are proxied by: https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/codehaus-snapshots/.

So declare the following `pluginRepository` to use SNAPSHOT versions of the tomcat-maven-plugin:

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>Codehaus Snapshots</id>
    <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/codehaus-snapshots</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Great tip. It solved my build problems. Thank you!
I just fail to understand how they could screw it up so bad that you get junk in your local repo and leave it unfixed for days?!

Comment: @veggen I saw [MOJO-1556](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1556) which mentions the problem and it looks like they reverted the change for now.